# Как получить доступ к сетевой директории из контейнера Docker?

Tags: java, linux, docker, сеть, принтер

Имеется сеть, в которой находится несколько сетевых принтеров. Данные принтеры доступны по путям вроде такого: `\\ServerName\PrinterName` *(для Windows)*.

Я пишу приложение на `Java`, которое будет отправлять документы на печать путём простой записи файла в сетевую директорию.

```java
File fileToPrint = new File(fileName);
File printerFolder = new File(printerName);

try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToPrint);
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(printerFolder)) {
    IOUtils.copy(fis, fos);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Данный код работает великолепно, когда я запускаю программу локально на своём компьютере *(Windows)*, который находится внутри сети. Но это перестаёт работать, если я запускаю `Docker`-контейнер в `wsl`.

Мой вопрос: каким образом я могу получить доступ к сетевым директориям из контейнера `Docker` *(в качестве базы для образа используется `linux`)*?

Comment: Windows за вас реализует доступ к удаленной папке. В Linux такого нет. Вам нужно либо монтировать smb://ServerName/PrinterName в докер (что несколько нетривиально), либо пользоваться библиотеками, реализующими доступ по протоколам CIFS/SMB, такими как [`jcifs-ng`](https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng) или [`smbj`](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj).

Comment: Там нет принтеров в маунте

Comment: Ну наверное - добавить в docker - `cups` и чё-то типа https://github.com/harwey/cups4j . Первое, что приходит на ум.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В линукс нет файлового доступа к сетевым папкам виндовс. Можно подключить доступ к файлам, но не к принтеру.

Можно попытаться печатать вызвав программу smbclient с некими параметрами и писать через неё.

Типовое решение - запустить cups. В cups подключить принтер. Печать выполнять через стандартные методы языка или через IPP или LPR.

Также можно установить IPP или LPR сервер сразу на windows.

Рекомендую IPP.

Comment: воспользовался cups-сервером, оказалось намного проще, чем делать маунт сетевой директории. Конечно, линукс меня неприятно удивил. На винде печать документа на сетевом принтере делалась в 6 строк кода без дополнительных библиотек. На линуксе пришлось аж отдельный контейнер в cups-сервером поднимать.

Comment: @Zhenyria это беда не линукса, а контейнеров. Так-то на линуксе тот же cups-сервер просто ставится из пакета и работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я воспользовался `CUPS`-сервером. Для этого я использовал `Docker image`    `olbat/cupsd` [ссылка](https://hub.docker.com/r/olbat/cupsd).

Подключение к серверу я выполнял при помощи библиотеки `cups4j`:

```java
try (var fileInputStream = getPrintingDocumentAsStream(documentName)) {
    CupsClient cupsClient = new CupsClient(cupsServerHost, cupsServerPort);
    CupsPrinter printer = cupsClient.getPrinter(printerName);

    if (Objects.isNull(printer)) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    PrintJob printJob = new PrintJob.Builder(fileInputStream).build();

    PrintRequestResult printRequestResult = printer.print(printJob);
    if (printRequestResult.isSuccessfulResult()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
}
```